# SQLite (5: database is locked) using FMDB Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, fmdb

I have used FMDB many times in my project. Now issues is that in my project only on particular screen(on all other screen insertion working pretty fine ) when I try to insert data it shows me logs like:

```
    Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (5: database is locked)

    DB Query: begin exclusive transaction

    Unknown error calling sqlite3_step (5: database is locked) eu

    DB Query: INSERT INTO topic_detail (topic_id, topic_name, ques_name, ques_id, ques_img, date,is_customised,ques_audio,isPredefined,default_image_url,default_audio_url,is_synced) VALUES ('4', 'Animals (mammals)', 'gbj', '542', 'updatedQuestionImages/queImg542.png', '02/12/2017', 'true', 'updatedQuestionAudios/queAud542.m4a','false','no','no','false')

    Error calling sqlite3_step (1: cannot commit - no transaction is active) SQLITE_ERROR

    Unknown error finalizing or resetting statement (1: cannot commit - no transaction is active)
```

And strange is that I can update records but can't insert. I checked all lines I closed all db connection. But don't know how this issue came. please suggest me solutions. I searched on google and stakeoverflow but nothing found helpfull.

Comment: did you add db.sqlite file in resource ?

Comment: did you close previous database ?

Comment: Yes copied and when I copied sqlite file from document directory to my desktop and opened in dbmanager and tried to insert manually then I am able to insert same data which I was trying to insert from device.